Unable to merge pdf watermark at the correct position
I'm writing a pdf editor in python with 3 function:

Delete the last page
Delete all blank page
Add Water Mark

I used a standard Water Mark subprogram, but the water mark keep been added to the wrong location         on a testing pdf. Is there something wrong with the code or the pdf? I'm thinking it's the pdf
from PyPDF2 import PdfMerger, PdfReader, PdfWriter

pdf_file = "sample.pdf"
watermark = "watermark.pdf"
merged = "result.pdf"

with open(pdf_file, "rb") as input_file, open(watermark, "rb") as watermark_file:
    input_pdf = PdfReader(input_file)
    watermark_pdf = PdfReader(watermark_file)
    watermark_page = watermark_pdf.pages[0]

    output = PdfWriter()

    for i in range(len(input_pdf.pages)):
        pdf_page = input_pdf.pages[i]
        pdf_page.merge_page(watermark_page)
        output.add_page(pdf_page)

    with open(merged, "wb") as merged_file:
        output.write(merged_file)

I saved it on replit.com so you can run it, the pdf is there as well
https://replit.com/@ygp3737/NavyNotedTypes#main.py
pdf

I followed the instruction, but the result is still the same, the watermark ain't at the same position on all pages.

Thank you so much, that overview explained a lot. What viewer did you use to get that overview? I think python(pypdf2) is definetly getting the odd overview instead of the page in the stardard pdf viewer. I think the odd overview is the "crop box", and the "normal" overview we see in a stardard pdf viewer is the "media box". Therefore it will be problem solve if I just either delete the crop box or force pypdf2 to use media box?

The problem here is that Python has already been used to corrupt a very good source imposition of a printable book. Which itself is a sampler from a publicly available MP4 Video book.
From comments this is a "Minimal Example" of another "private" layout since the publicly printable books here are published in the Public Domain (WWW.littlefox.com), and thus unnecessary to attempt watermarking a part, especially as it's an Adobe InDesign 17.0 (Windows) Imposition, hence already corrupted by a prior PyPDF2 modification.
Here we can see the desired format includes a reversed double layout as page 2 is supposed to be folded or slit in a Print House.

I would suggest you get the source document and use that for printing rather than an inferior copy So when printed some of the 14 pages will be "upside down" and they can then be more easily rotated as PDF pages rather than fiddling the way PyPDF was used. I personally would not bother adding a watermark to a published document, as they can be more easily removed than this more problematic issue of rotating printable output.
https://res.littlefox.com/en/supplement/load_pdf/C0005234?_=242424

Programming Answer
In your OS shell you need two lines of code.
The first is to decimate the pages in half so could be the equivalence of
Mutool poster -x 1 -y 2 -o book-out.pdf book-in.pdf

That works very well for splitting 7 pages into 14
The second program line is to rotate even pages except 2 so rotate 4, 6.... This is now the hardest part, since mutool has no easy way to selectively rotate. The result would only be the 6 rotated pages, and then we would have more problems.
Thus both coded actions are best done another way.
The simplest would be to replace the first mutool instruction with coherent
cpdf -chop-h 421 in.pdf -o out.pdf

However I can't show you that as is version 2.7+ and I only have last 32 bit prior version 2.6 ! The second line of code would then be use cpdf to rotate the selected pages.
cpdf -decrypt-force -rotate 180 bat1.pdf 4,6,8,10,12,14 -o out.pdf

All the pages will now be viewable correct way up.

Finally
cpdf also has watermarking functions that can be applied in combination with the above 2 lines and in theory all 3 steps combined using AND in the code.
For details see Chapter 8 Watermarks and Stamps in the manual for many text or image or import options.


This is only a practise, as you said it's absurd to add watermark to a opensourced pdf which can be removed without any efford.

Thank you so much, the program is working now. Just to be clear, the program is designed for a group of classifed document which cannot be revealed on the internet, and I happen to find this pdf has the same "problem" as the classified one, hence I utlized this document as a replacement sample.
